# munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

Tags: c

I've spotted the error in my program and decided to write a simple one, which would help me understand what's going on. Here it is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * first()
{
    char * word = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    word[0] = 'a';
    word[1] = 'b';
    word[2] = '\0';
    return word;
}

char * second ()
{
    char * word = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    word = "ab";
    return word;
}

int main ()
{
    char * out = first();
    printf("%s", out);
    free(out);
    out = second();
    printf("%s", out);
    free(out);
    return 0;
}
```

The `first()` function is working properly, but the `second()` (exactly the `free(out)` ) genarates error:

> Error in `./a.out': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400714 ***
>   ababAborted (core dumped)

I don't understand why the first function is correct, but the second isn't. Could anyone explain why?

Comment: You can't directly assign a string to a char array, use `strcpy(word, "ab")`.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

In the function `second()`, the assignment `word = "ab";` assigns a new pointer to `word`, overwriting the pointer obtained through `malloc()`. When you call `free()` on the pointer later on, the program crashes because you pass a pointer to `free()` that has not been obtained through `malloc()`.

Assigning string literals does not have the effect of copying their content as you might have thought. To copy the content of a string literal, use `strcpy()`:

```
strcpy(word, "ab");
```

Comment: But what exactly is munmap_chunk() mean? Can it just not be segfault ( as pointer passed to free is not wrt to malloc() ). And what are the other scenarios where the munmap_chunk() invalid pointer issue would arise?

Comment: @SathvikSat `munmap_chunk()` is an internal function of the libc's memory management routine.  This error message means that by writing into memory that does not belong to an object (but belongs to your process so no segfault), you corrupted internal data structures belonging to these routines.  Trying to use these corrupted data structures, the internal routines crash.

Answer (score 23):

In function `char * second`

```
 char * word = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
 word = "ab";
```

The second statement `word = "ab";` changes `word` to point away from the allocated memory.You are not copying the string `"ab"` to the area of heap allocated by `malloc`.

And to `free` a memory that is not allocated by `malloc` or similar functions crashes  your program.

> Attempting to free an invalid pointer (a pointer to a memory block that was not allocated by calloc, malloc, or realloc) may affect subsequent allocation requests and cause errors.

You should use here `strcpy` as also suggested by others.