# Why am I getting this error and how to fix it: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400694 *** Hello WorldAborted

Tags: c, string, dynamic-memory-allocation

I wrote the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
        char *s;
        s = (char*)malloc(15);
        s = "Hello World";
        printf("%s",s);
        free(s);
        return 0;
  }
```

There are no compilation errors.
I'm getting this run time error:
*** Error in `./s': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400694 ***
Hello WorldAborted

Why am I getting this run time error and how can I fix it? 
Is it because after the call to `malloc`, `s` received a certain address, and the assignment `s = "Hello World"` modifies the address of `s`, but then when doing `free(s)`, the pointer that is sent to `free` is not the one that was returned by `malloc`?

Comment: Your explanation is correct.

Comment: BTW, there is no need to cast `void`-pointers in C.

Comment: Right, thank you  @alk

Comment: Possible duplicate  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118545/munmap-chunk-invalid-pointer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [munmap\_chunk(): invalid pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118545/munmap-chunk-invalid-pointer)

Answer (score 6):

> Is it because after the call to malloc, s received a certain address,
>   and the assignment s = "Hello World" modifies the address of s, but
>   then when doing free(s), the pointer that is sent to free is not the
>   one that was returned by malloc?

Yes

```
    s = (char*)malloc(15);
    s = "Hello World";
```

You are overwriting the returned address of `malloc` (memory leak)

[free()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/free.html)

> if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the
>   calloc(), malloc(), posix_memalign(), realloc(), or strdup() function,
>   or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free() or realloc(),
>   the behavior is undefined.

Change `s = "Hello World";` to `strcpy(s, "Hello world");`

Also, take a look to [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/1606345)

Comment: Thank you very much! @Keine Lust

Comment: @Keine Lust
Actually, I'm confused....why would not it be strcpy(&s, "Hello world"); ? I mean if we send s, then why a copy of the pointer s will not be made?
Say I have int x = 4; and I send it into a function that receives an int. Then if I understand it well, a copy of that integer is going to be made, in a different address containing the same content of x, which is 4.
So if I pass s into a function, why a copy of the pointer s won't be made?
Where did I go wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: No, `strcpy` is expecting a pointer to `char` and `s` is already a pointer to `char` (using the address of operator `&s` results in a pointer to pointer).

Comment: @Keine Lust Thanks for responding quickly :)  So in the call strcpy(s,"Hello World"); the address of s is passed to strcpy?

Comment: @Keine Lust Thanks, just one last thing: I still don't understand ,when we do need to pass a pointer to pointer to something, and when the address of the pointer itself is passed? 
Because sometimes I see things like **ptr passed into functions, but with strcpy for example, we don't need to do so.

Comment: @Keine Lust Thank you, I appreciate it.