# free allocated memory in function

Tags: c, split, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, function-definition

i have function which is written in c ,in this function i allocate 2 string as temp and found, but i cant free temp string.
i think it may due to using of temp in result array.
can any one helps me.
here is the function.

```
void split(char* input, char* delim, char** result,int size) {

    char* tmp = malloc((strlen(input)) * sizeof(char));
    char* found = malloc((strlen(input)) * sizeof(char)); 
    
    tmp=strcpy(tmp, input);

    // #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        found = strstr(tmp, delim);
        if (found != NULL) {

            int length = found - tmp;
            result[i]=malloc((length+1) * sizeof(char));
            result[i] = strncpy(result[i], tmp, length);
            *(result[i] + length) = '\0';
            tmp = found + strlen(delim);

        } else {

            result[i]=malloc(strlen(tmp) * sizeof(char));
            result[i] =strncpy(result[i], tmp, strlen(tmp));
  
        }
    }

    // free(tmp);
    free(found);
}
```

here size is number of sub strings after split

when i remove the comment of  this line:
// free(tmp);
then this err occurs:

```
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

can i ask you to help me for writing correct split function

Comment: Yea, because you reassign the pointers. `free` can only be called on the pointer which was originally given to you by `malloc`/`calloc`/etc. Attempting to free any other pointer is undefined behavior and will probably cause some sort of error.

Comment: Did you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32118638/10458514) ? You first assign it with malloc, but then you reassign it using strcpy, then again in your if condition

Answer (score 1):

You do assignments to `tmp`. That means the pointer `tmp` might no longer point to the same location that `malloc` returned.

You need to pass the *exact* same pointer to `free` that was returned by `malloc`.

You have the same problem with `found`, you assign to it and possible change where it points.

Passing an invalid pointer to `free` leads to *undefined behavior*.

---

You *also* have another problem: You go out of bounds of the original memory allocated and pointed to by `tmp`. That's because you seem to have forgotten that strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** strings*.

When you allocate memory for a string, you need to include space for the null-terminator at the end. And it's not counted by `strlen`.

Going out of bounds of allocated memory also leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: should i keep the address of original pointers at first ,before any change and then pass that addresses to free?

Comment: you mean my another problem in else?
@Some programmer dude

Answer (score 1):

The function does not make a sense.

For starters it invokes undefined behavior

```
char* tmp = malloc((strlen(input)) * sizeof(char));
char* found = malloc((strlen(input)) * sizeof(char)); 

tmp=strcpy(tmp, input);
//...
```

because you allocated to enough memory to store the terminating zero character '\0' of the string input in the character array `tmp`.

Secondly the function has a memory leak because at first memory was allocated and its address was assigned to the pointer `found` and then the pointer `found` was reassigned in the call of `strstr` in the for loop.

```
char* found = malloc((strlen(input)) * sizeof(char)); 

//...

// #pragma omp parallel for
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    found = strstr(tmp, delim);
    //...
```

So the address of the early allocated memory is lost and the memory can not be freed.

And this for loop

```
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
```

is just senseless.

You may not call `free` neither for `tmp` nor for `found`. The pointer `found` does not point to a dynamically allocated memory and the pointer `tmp` is being changed within the for loop.

Comment: should i keep the address of original pointers at first ,before any change and then pass that addresses to free?

Comment: can i ask you to help me for writing split function

Comment: @zahra You have to pass to free the same value of a pointer that was assigned to it by a call of malloc.

Comment: i dont know how can you help me please.
@Vlad from Moscow

Answer (score 0):

here is my new function. i wrote it in recursive mode.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_number_of_occurence(char* string, char* delim) {

    char* found = strstr(string, delim);
 
    if(found == NULL || strcmp(found,delim) ==0 ||found =="" ){
        
        return 0;

    }else{
      
        return 1+get_number_of_occurence(found+strlen(delim), delim);
      
    }
}

int split(char* input, char* delim, char** result,int array_idx) {

    char* found= strstr(input, delim);

    if (found==""||strlen(input)==0){
        return 0;

    }else if(found == NULL){
    
        result[array_idx]=malloc(strlen(input)+1 * sizeof(char));
        strncpy(result[array_idx], input, strlen(input));
        *(result[array_idx] + strlen(input)) = '\0';
        return 0;

    }else{

        int length = found - input;
        result[array_idx]=malloc((length+1) * sizeof(char));
        strncpy(result[array_idx], input, length);
        *(result[array_idx] + length) = '\0';
        return split(found+strlen(delim),delim,result,array_idx+1); 
    }
}
int main () {

char * delim = "ooo";
char * input="ssooonn";

int size = get_number_of_occurence(input, delim);
printf("size is : %d \n",size);

char *splitted_values[size+1];

split(input, delim,splitted_values,0);

for (int i=0; i<(size+1); i++) {
    printf("%s\n",splitted_values[i]);
    free(splitted_values[i]);
}

}
```

in this code, first i count the number of occurrence of delimiter.

then i create array in that size and fill it with the help of split function.

thanks for helping.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).